# How to clear console messages in Capybara (Driver: capybara-webkit)

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using Capybara with the `capybara-webkit` driver.

I can access console messages with

```
page.driver.console_messages
```

Is there an easy way to clear the messages, similar to how I would in a live browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not (while leaving the page alone), however they do get cleared when the driver is reset (normally between each test)